# Losing messages from a topic with DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I'm using a DefaultMessageListenerContainer to consume messages from a topic (Broker is ActiveMQ). Because the consumers are created at runtime i'm doing the following:

1) I have a Conainer Template configured in spring

```
<bean id="topiccontainertemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" scope="prototype" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionfactory" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="default" />
</bean>
```

2) When a new consumer is required i get a new one from the application conext and reconfigure the destinationName.

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = context.getBean("topiccontainertemplate", DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
container.setDestinationName(localEntity.getId().getDestination());
container.setMessageListener(getListener());
container.start();
```

Unfortunately the container misses some messages on the topic.
Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'some messages'?  Are they initial messages or is it intermittent?

Comment: @sully6768 its not the initial messages. some messages in the middle seem to vanish (I'm still investigating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more tests we found a race condition during consumer creation. the messages weren't lost, they weren't distributed properly in our code.

Comment: They might have been lost if the cache level would be lower than CACHE_CONSUMERS. As Petter said above, during the consumer recreation, all messages for non-durable subscription are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Your subscription does not look durable. If it was, messages would have been saved while your sub is offline/ starting up. Your subscriber will get msgs from the point it is started completly - msgs sent prior to that will be lost.